# Visually changing URL in browser

Tags: javascript, url, browser, cross-browser

I want to visually (not affecting real address) change URL in browser address bar, like this:

```
Real:  http://www.example.com/example_a_b_c.html
Shown: http://www.example.com/e_a_b_c
```

(I may also want to change domain name, if I could)

It would be much nicer if there is an option to use any simple Javascript code or function. I don't actually know the language, so I'm only looking for a little code that would fit into an HTML `<script>` tag, just for myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: Do you want the word "example" to be removed? I suppose you'll want to put the code in multiple pages, not only in one, right?

Comment: Thanks, I will read that article.

Comment: Oh, I don't know. May be. As I said - I don't actually know the JS language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the **[History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/History)**, and, more precisely, using the `history.pushState()` method.

An example of this, in your case, would be:

```
history.pushState(null, null, '/e_a_b_c');
```

To answer your other question:

> I may also want to change domain name, if I could.

Unfortunately **you can't**, that would be a huge security flaw, and it's not possible at all.

Comment: Thanks, would definitely try that one!

Comment: Sorry, I did not include that I also want to know how change it to completely different domain, sorry. Now it is.

Comment: Thanks. Just as I thought, you can't do that. But thanks anyway!